# Integers, call function every X number

Tags: ios, math, parse-platform, int

I have an app that has a game style element to it even though its not a game, I have game center working and would like to notify the current device user every time 100 'Chatters' have joined their Group/Forum. I will give users in-app DLC free of charge once they reach certain milestones (1k subscribed/joined Chatters etc)

So i'm trying to notify users every X number of subs using Parse.com but having difficulties repeating this every 100 times. I was able to make it work this way but it's getting kind of tiresome adding these manually. is there a built in API method that makes this easier?

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Groups"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"------vNDd" block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
[object incrementKey:@"Group_Chatters" byAmount:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
[object saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        NSNumber *objectNumber = [object valueForKey:@"Group_Chatters"];
        int subscribers = [objectNumber intValue];
        if ([self subscribersIsNewMilestone:subscribers]) {
            //Send Notification
        }
    } else {

    }
}];
}];

-(BOOL)subscribersIsNewMilestone:(int)subscribers {
  int i = subscribers + 1; //This will include the new subscription that just happened

  if ((i == 100) || (i == 200) || (i == 300) || (i == 400) || (i == 500) || etc etc etc ) {
      return YES;
  } else {
      return NO;
  }
}
```

Comment: why not just `if (i % 100 == 0)`

Comment: What does that do @shim ? I don't know how to do much math with floats and integers in xcode thats why i'm asking easier way with API

Comment: @shim thank you that worked. can you please offer that as an answer so i can credit you for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the modulo operator (`%`)

i.e. in your case:

```
if (i % 100 == 0) {
...
```

This if statement will be true everytime i is divisible by 100. NOTE: 0 % 100 is also 0, but in your case this shouldn't be an issue because you always add 1.

The modulo operator `%` returns the remainder of the left operand divided by the right operand. It is present in practically all modern programming languages. More on it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

e.g.

```
int x = 10
x % 2 // 0 because 10 / 2 = 5, remainder 0
x % 3 // 1 because 10 / 3 = 3, remainder 1
x % 0 // division by zero error, because 10 / 0 is undefined
```